# What's wrong with my "intersects" algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, collision-detection, intersection

Modeling closely to Java AWT's [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) class, I have my `Rectangle` POJO:

```
public class Rectangle {
    // The Coordinate of the upper-left corner of the Rectangle.
    private Coordinate upperLeft;   // upperLeft.getXVal() and upperLeft.getYVal()

    // The width of the Rectangle.
    private BigDecimal width;

    // The height of the Rectangle.
    private BigDecimal height;

    // Determine if we intersect otherRectangle.
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        BigDecimal x = otherRectangle.getUpperLeft().getXVal();
        BigDecimal y = otherRectangle.getUpperLeft().getYVal();
        BigDecimal w = otherRectangle.getWidth();
        BigDecimal h = otherRectangle.getHeight();
        BigDecimal x0 = getUpperLeft().getXVal();
        BigDecimal y0 = getUpperLeft().getYVal();

        if(isEmpty() || w.doubleValue() <= 0.0 || h.doubleValue() <= 0.0)
            return false;

        return (
            x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue() > x0.doubleValue() &&
            y.doubleValue() + h.doubleValue() > y0.doubleValue() &&
            x.doubleValue() < x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue() &&
            y.doubleValue() < y0.doubleValue() + getHeight().doubleValue()
        );
    }
}
```

When I execute the following code:

```
// r1 has upperLeft corner at (0,4), width = 6, height = 4
// r2 has upperLeft corner at (5,1), width = 2, height = 1
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(new Coordinate(0,4), 6, 4);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(new Coordinate(5,1), 2, 1);

boolean result = r1.intersects(r2);
```

The answer is false! Stepping through the code in the debugger, I see the reason is because of the 2nd `AND` clause in the return value:

```
return (
    x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue() > x0.doubleValue() &&
    y.doubleValue() + h.doubleValue() > y0.doubleValue() &&     <=== problem is here
    x.doubleValue() < x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue() &&
    y.doubleValue() < y0.doubleValue() + getHeight().doubleValue()
);
```

When the above code runs, `y=1`, `h=1` and `y0=4`. Obviously, `1+1 > 4` is **false**. So this is definitely a bug in my algorithm, but I copied it straight from `Rectangle2D#intersect`, and don't see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: But your two example Rectangles don't intersect.

Comment: But your rectangles **don't** intersect...

Comment: Thanks @Edgar Boda (+1) - but how so? r1 has an upper left corner of (0,4), so all of its coords would be (0,0), (0,4), (6,4) and (6,0). r2s coords are (5,0), (5,1), (7,1) and (7,0). r2 is "cut in half" by the right side of r1

Comment: Thanks @OliCharlesworth (+1) - but can you explain how? See my comment above where I explain all the other coordinates (which are derived from upperLeft, width and height). Ideas?

Comment: you are substracting height and adding width.... its wrong, you need to add x+width and y+height. r1 would be: (0,4), (6,4), (0,8), (6, 8) and r2 would be (5,1),(7,1),(5,2),(7,2)

Comment: Thanks @EdgarBoda (+1 again) - however what you're saying doesn't make sense! Doesn't "upper-left" corner mean the **upper-left** corner! To me, that means go `width` units to the right and find your upper-right corner. Go `height` units down to get your lower-left corner, and go both `width` units right and `height` units down to get your lower-right corner. How am I doing it backwards here?!?! Thanks again!

Comment: Then you need to change the line in your return like this i think: `y.doubleValue() - h.doubleValue() < y0.doubleValue()`

Comment: Thanks again @EdgarBoda (+1) - but now I'm getting even more confused. So let's back up a step: either I have modelled `Rectangle` correctly and am passing in correct data, but the algorithm is wrong. **Or**, I am passing in bad data (i.e. 2 rectangles that truly don't intersect given the way I am modelling `Rectangle`) and my algorithm is correct. **Soo....** I need an algorithm that works where the upper-left corner truly is the upper-left corner of the rectangle, and where width is added and height is subtracted (otherwise upper-left isn't truly the upper-left)...

Comment: So I first need to figure out which is wrong: the data or the algorithm. If the data is wrong, I need someone to explain to me how it could possible be wrong, if upper-left means what I think it does. If the algorithm is wrong, then I need an answer that helps me fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: Your algorithm is fine if you change the line as I wrote above. As you have it now, your upperLeft is in fact the lowerLeft corner. You take your point and add width and height, so it is as you said the lowerLeft corner. If you change it to substracting the height it will become the upperLeft corner as you wanted it ;) Actually in these cases it's easiest if you take a piece of paper and just draw the two rectangles and figure out what conditions you need to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an upperLeft corner you need to check the following conditions to **not** have an intersection:

**Any** of the following need to apply and you will not have an intersection:

1. this.x + this.width < other.x (other rectangle to the right of this rectangle)
2. other.x + other.width < this.x (other rectangle to the left of this rectangle)
3. this.y - this.height > other.y (other rectangle below this rectangle)
4. other.y - other.height > this.y (other rectangle above this rectangle)

So to calculate an intersection you just negate the above:

```
return !( //notice the !
  x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue() < x0.doubleValue() ||
  y.doubleValue() - h.doubleValue() > y0.doubleValue() ||     
  x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue() < x.doubleValue() ||
  y0.doubleValue() - getHeight().doubleValue() > y.doubleValue()
);
```

Or if you want to pull the `NOT` inside:

```
 return (
  x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue() >= x0.doubleValue() &&
  y.doubleValue() - h.doubleValue() <= y0.doubleValue() &&     
  x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue() >= x.doubleValue() &&
  y0.doubleValue() - getHeight().doubleValue() <= y.doubleValue()
);
```